# Paraphrasing a sentence

Tags: writing

> Annie said that she couldn't do anything with Helen Keller unless she had her all to herself.

I'd like to paraphrase the sentence as the following.

> 1. Annie wanted to have Helen all to herself **because she wanted to control her completely.**
> 2. Annie wanted to have Helen all to herself **so that she could manage her completely.**

Are my sentences correct in meaning to the original sentences?

Comment: There's some context missing here. Having seen movies about Helen Keller and Anne Sullivan, Anne wanted to control Helen's surroundings. Helen was used to just grabbing whatever she wanted, screaming if she wanted something, etc. Anne wanted to remove that context to teach Helen manners and teach Helen to calmly communicate (through sign language).

Answer (score 3):

I think it means:

> Annie wanted the complete and undivided attention of Helen.

The second sentence is almost correct. But I wouldn't use "manage". Manage is to control. I don't think Annie wanted to control Helen, but wanted her complete attention, so as to help her.

Answer (score 3):

When you talk about "controlling" a person, that has the connotation of dominating that person, of forcing them to do what you want. That's generally viewed as a very negative thing. Like, "My wife is always trying to control me!" We talk about prison guards "controlling" the prisoners, etc. Adding "completely" makes it more extreme, like she's trying to make Helen her slave. So unless you are trying to portray Anne Sullivan as an evil, manipulative person, this is probably not a good choice of words.

"Manage" is more neutral, but is still probably not what the original sentence meant. To "manage" someone is to direct their activities. Like a boss manages his employees.

I presume that what the writer meant was that Anne didn't want to have many people all trying to teach Helen in different ways so that Helen became distracted and confused. She wanted to be her only teacher.

Answer (score 0):

> ...all to herself.

Means **without outside influence or interference**, there is a certain amount of controlling and **not sharing** which is implied, but the controlling may or may not be egregious to the point of domination.  Imagine that Anne got what she wanted, consider the statement:

> She had Helen Keller **all to herself**.

This means Anne **only had to deal with Helen Keller** and no one else around Helen Keller: doctors, nurses, relatives, pets, etc. and also that Anne could **make any and all decisions** she wanted to about Helen Keller.

> I wanted the bowl of cereal **all to myself**.

Not only means, I **do not want to share** my cereal, but also I don't want anyone telling me **how** to eat my cereal (with milk, without milk, how much milk...)